# Determining value of NSUInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I'd like to view the value of an NSUInteger at any given time.  I assign the value below:

```
NSUInteger test = -1;
```

Then try to view it in the debugger:

```
(gdb) po test
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff
(gdb) p test
$1 = 4294967295
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Far as I know, it is a value type.  Where is -1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're using an `NSUInteger`, which is unsigned. As such, any negative values assigned will actually be interpreted very large positive values.

You want to use `NSInteger` which is signed (and therefore can be both positive and negative values). You should then be able to do `(gdb) p test` to see the value.

Comment: It's also not a pointer to an object, which is what po expects to be given.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I compare an NSInteger value to a NSUInteger value?

Comment: If you know for certain that they are within the overlap range, you can cast NSUInteger to NSInteger in order to compare them. But before putting in a typecast, always carefully consider if the numbers will *always* be in an appropriate range.

Comment: The single line you give is pretty much totally a contradiction.  You say you want an unsigned number, then right away you give the number a negative sign.

Why not just make the values you are using NSInteger?